# Difference between Date and CreationDate in TestCaseResult

Tags: rally

In the WSAPI, what is the difference between the "CreationDate" field and the "Date" field for "TestCaseResult" objects?

The "Date" field seems to be later than the creation date, and in the doc it says: Date that the test case was run to produce this result

I've these two dates off by six or seven hours on automated tests.  Why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike CreationDate, which is read-only and automatically populated by Rally to be the actual date/time of Creation of the TCR, Date is write-able and can be set by the testing automation (in the case of automated testing) or, the user running manual tests. It can be used to post-date TCR's that are created by an automation via a batch process that runs at intervals, to accurately reflect the actual Date/Time that the test was run.

Comment: Ok-- so basically whomever logs the result sets this value to whatever they wish.  Thanks!